# Purpose of /etc/X11/Xsession.d files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, xorg, session

I'm with linux and have some questions about Xsession. As I understand `/etc/X11/Xsession` script is launched when X Window System session is begun. But as I was examining code in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` I got little confused. Scripts here are launched in order, `99x11-common_start` is last one which contains `exec $STARTUP` I logged this variable and its just `init --user`. So it turns out that whole this script is written to just launch init --user? I deleted some files and logged in with different user and everything worked well, (for example `75dbus_dbus-launch`). Does it mean that Xsession only launches `init --user`? What about session dbus, who launches it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is two DBus daemon launched at boot: `--session` & `--system`. The one in Xsession is session bus (user owns it).

```
~$ ps aux | grep dbus-daemon
message+   944  0.0  0.0  44504  5640 ?        Ss   07:55   0:01 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
sneetsh+  2428  0.0  0.0  43864  4340 ?        Ss   07:56   0:00 dbus-daemon --fork --session --address=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-xcqH0l6FdF
sneetsh+  2522  0.0  0.0  43028  3932 ?        S    07:56   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
sneetsh+  4593  0.0  0.0  14328   964 pts/19   S+   08:17   0:00 grep --color=auto dbus-daemon
```

The above output was from Ubuntu **16.04** and uses `systemd`.

- System bus is launched by `systemd`

  ```
  ~$ service dbus status
  ● dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-07-06 07:55:13 CET; 27min ago
       Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
   Main PID: 944 (dbus-daemon)
      Tasks: 1
     Memory: 3.5M
        CPU: 1.574s
     CGroup: /system.slice/dbus.service
             └─944 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
  ```
- Session bus is launched by `upstart`

  ```
  ~$ initctl status dbus 
  dbus start/running, process 2428

  ~$ initctl show-config dbus 
  dbus
    start on starting xsession-init
  ```

  (Be aware this session upstart daemon, NOT init/system upstart one)

Ubuntu before **15.10** uses upstart init.

You can verify these using `pstree -up`. Another, way you may log `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable from the file you have removed like you did with `STARTUP`.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. One more question please, I created little script in bash that would log `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` in file, I tried to put this file in `/etc/profile.d` and `/etc/init.d` but I had no luck. Looks like "pre login" place where I could put this file. Could you please tell me where can I put it?